# Is it ok to say "call with <person>"

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I am trying to find any vocabulary that has some examples of the subj.
I am interested in using the "call" as a noun, not verb.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/call
https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/call

Everywhere I see "call to" (i.e. "a call to technical support"). And if I want to express that I had a chat with some person, is it correct to say "I had a call with "?

Comment: "An instance of speaking to someone on the phone or attempting to contact someone by phone." **not conversation** -- you do not use *call* to mean the conversation itself.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between "speaking to someone on the phone" and having a conversation; the former is generally considered to include them speaking back to you, it refers to a two-way chat not just delivering a monologue, and hence is a conversation.

Comment: " She’d call neither Paula with her love for Drambuie nor Gillian with her willingness to pick up the pieces of the messes she left behind."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to express that you experienced a phone conversation with somebody, yes, it is correct to say "I had a call with..." in the same way you could say "I had a chat with..." when you don't want to specify how or if you met face to face for a few drinks "I had some drinks with..."

That happens because the construction actually comes from the verb *to have* meaning *experience* and not from the noun *call*. Check the definition #2 [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/have)

Comment: Logically, yes. However, see also my comment at OP above.

Comment: @Kris Please take into account [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) is also happening in this phrase, so, yes, you can still use "call" to refer to the conversation itself as "I had a conversation via phone call with my friend" is simplified into " I had a call with my friend".

Comment: I am not aware of any reliable source that includes the conversation sense of *call*. So, metonymy notwithstanding, I am unconvinced.

Comment: @Kris [Lexico, 3rd definition of call as a noun](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/call), [Merriam-Webster, 8th definition of the noun, that feeds into definition 1m of the verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call?). Those are very explicit in the communication sense.

Comment: Lexico: that's what the OP had cited and I commented as very clear that it is the **instance** of and not the **content** of a call. Note.

Comment: Btw, if the OP is convinced from the references cited, then what remains to be answered now?

Comment: @Kris Note: my point is that the most important part on defining if "call" is appropriate or not is that a phone is the means of holding the communication, regardless of it being one way or both ways (as Stuart F mentioned in the comment). I'm still not sure on what is not clear on that considering all the additional references.

Answer (score 0):

> **I made  a   call  to  my  friend**
>
> **I   got  or  received  a call  from  my  friend**

These  are  idiomatic

**I  had  a call  with  my my  friend** is  possible

**I  had   a   talk  with  my  friend    is  idiomatic**

Comment: “I had a call from my friend” is not idiomatic to me. You don’t _have_ calls in this context; you _make_ them _to_ someone, or you _get_ them _from_ someone. “I got a call from my friend” is idiomatic. I’m not sure I quite agree that “I had a call with my friend” is unidiomatic; it’s definitely less common, but in context, I doubt I would notice it as sounding off. “So I had a call with the boss to clarify, and it turns out the deadline has actually been moved forward to this Friday” sounds fairly unremarkable to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I find both *I had a call with* and *I had a call from* to be quite idiomatic and natural, at least here in Canada. It's informal, but it's common.I have no idea if it might be something about US English versus UK English—I get both.